# OpenCV findEssentialMat() and recoverPose() sign convention?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation

If I have two images L and R taken from left and right cameras, respectively, and I am calling the essential matrix function as follows:

E = findEssentialMat(rightImagePoints, leftImagePoints, ...), and then subsequently recoverPose(E, rightImagePoints, leftImagePoints)..

The sign in the translation vector I am getting in the end is not [-1, 0, 0] as it should be (because I am calculating pose of camera L from camera R) but [1, 0, 0].. can anyone explain why to me please? I naturally assumed it would be looking for a chirality between points1 and points2 if the functions are passed points in the order points1, points2. Which camera is being considered as origin in my function call?